# Does c++ compiler optimize a = b + c

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, compiler-optimization

**Whover downvoted me, mind explaining why? I thought it was a legitimate question, and all the answers have been very helpful.**

Theoretically, when I do `MyClass a = b + c`, it should first call `const MyClass operator+`, returning a `const MyClass` object, then call the assignment operator to create object a.

It seems like I would copy stuff twice when returning a object and calling the assignment operator. Is this optimized in the compiler? If yes, how?  It seems more tricky if it involves casting.

Let's assume we are talking about g++, which is pretty much the golden standard of c++ compilers. [EDIT: ok, let's say most commonly used]

[EDIT:] Whoa, I didn't expect using const in return-by-value be criticized. I thought it was enouraged to use const when return-by-value for non-built-in types? I remember seeing it somewhere.

Comment: Surely it would depend on which compiler you're using.

Comment: It's generally a Bad Idea to return a `const MyClass`, because that foils move semantics.

Comment: I say it also depends on the `operator+` itself and whether it can be inlined.

Comment: There is no assignment operator, neither theoretical nor otherwise.

Comment: The golden standard is, arguably, Clang.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks for the comments.  I thought it was enouraged to use const when return-by-value for non-built-in types? I remember seeing it somewhere.

Comment: @CodeNoob Definitely not since move semantics where introduced - move constructors practically never take `const` rvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy-initialisation doesn't use the assignment operator, it uses the copy or move constructor. Since your operator foolishly returns a `const` object, moving is impossible, so it would use the copy constructor.

However, initialising an object from a temporary is one of the situations where *copy elision* is allowed, so any decent compiler should do that, initialising `a` directly as the return value instead of creating a temporary.

Comment: There was an argument once that for identical types of variable and initializer expressions it *has* to do copy elision, but I can't recall. Argh.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I have made some edits. I didn't expect using const in return-by-value be criticized. I thought it was enouraged to use const when return-by-value for non-built-in types? I remember seeing it somewhere

Comment: @CodeNoob: Some people used to suggest it (so that weird code like `a+b=c` would fail to compile, instead of giving weird behaviour), but these days move semantics make it a bad idea, since you can't move from a constant object.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers will optimise this using *copy-elision*. The temporary created from calling `MyClass::operator+` will be constructed directly into `a` rather than calling the copy constructor.

Also note that `MyClass a = ...` does not call the assignment operator, it calls the copy constructor. This is known as copy-initialization.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization/12953150#12953150) for more information on copy elision.

Comment: What's the downvote for? Did I say something incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

There is an optimization called copy elision, described by the standard in §12.8/31:

> This elision of copy/move operations, called *copy elision*, is
>   permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to
>   eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>     non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-
>     unqualified type as the function return type, **the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
>     the automatic object directly into the function’s return value**
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
>     cv-unqualified type, **the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>     omitted copy/move**

Thus in the line

```
MyClass a = b + c;
```

The temporary object returned by `operator+` is **directly constructed into `a`**, and no unnecessary copies/moves occur, not even in the `return` statement in `operator+`. A demonstration:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int i;

    MyClass operator+( MyClass const& m ) {
        MyClass r = m.i + i;
        return r;
    }

    MyClass(int i) : i(i) {std::cout << "Ctor!\n";}
    // Move ctor not implicitly declared, see §12.8/9
    MyClass(MyClass const&) {std::cout << "Copy-Ctor!\n";}
    ~MyClass() {std::cout << "* Dtor!\n";}
};

int main() {
    MyClass c{7}, b{3},
            a = b + c;
}
```

Output on any decent compiler:

> Ctor!
>  Ctor!
>  Ctor!
>   * Dtor!
>   * Dtor!
>   * Dtor!

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e396398e099e2a4e)

Answer (score 0):

To give a more direct idea of what you can expect, let's start with a simple class like this:

```
class Integer {
    int a;
    public:
    Integer(int a) : a(a) {}

    friend Integer operator+(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Integer(a.a + b.a);
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Integer const &i) {
        return os << i.a;
    }
};
```

For the sake of demonstration, let's add a `main` that reads some data from the outside world, creates a couple of Integer objects, and then prints out the result of adding them. The inputs and outputs will come from the outside world, so the compiler can't pull *too* fancy of tricks, and optimize everything out.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Integer a(atoi(argv[1])), b(atoi(argv[2]));
    Integer c = a + b;    // Line 20
    std::cout << c;
}
```

Note the `line 20` there--it becomes important below.

Now, let's compile it up and see what code the compiler produces. Using VC++ we get this:

[ normal "stuff" to set up entry to `main` elided ]

```
; Line 19
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rdx+8]
    mov rdi, rdx
    call    atoi
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
    mov ebx, eax
    call    atoi
; Line 20
    lea edx, DWORD PTR [rax+rbx]
; Line 21
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
```

So even though we've created two Integer objects and added them using an overloaded operator that constructs and returns a third Integer object, the compiler has seen through all our subterfuge, and "realized" that what we're doing is just reading a couple of `int`s using `atoi`, adding them together, and printing out the `int` we get as a result.

Having seen that, it eliminates the function call completely and doesn't call or return anything--it just reads two ints, adds them together, and prints out the result.

Using gcc the result is pretty much the same:

```
movq    8(%rbx), %rcx
call    atoi                    ; <--- get first item
movq    16(%rbx), %rcx
movl    %eax, %esi
call    atoi                    ; <--- get second item
movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rcx
leal    (%rsi,%rax), %edx       ; <--- the addition
call    _ZNSolsEi               ; <--- print result
```

It's rearranged the code slightly, but ultimate does pretty much the same thing--all vestiges of our `Integer` class have disappeared.

Let's compare that to what we get without using a class at all:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    int c = a + b;
    std::cout << c;
}
```

Using VC++, this produces the following:

```
; Line 5
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rdx+8]
    mov rdi, rdx
    call    atoi
; Line 6
    mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi+16]
    mov ebx, eax
    call    atoi
; Line 7
    lea edx, DWORD PTR [rbx+rax]
; Line 8
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
```

Other than the comments showing the line numbers from the original file, the code is *precisely* identical to what we got using the class.

I won't waste the space to copy and paste the result from doing the same with g++; it also produces identical code regardless of whether we use our class and overloaded operator to do the addition or not.